# how to find a valid Private ip address of the machine out of all the interfaces?

Tags: networking, docker, amazon-ec2, ip-address

My main objective is to find out the valid interface's private IP address in Linux machine.

e.g. I have 7 interfaces and out of 7 I have two interfaces docker0 with IP address of `172.12.2.1` and `eth0 172.23.32.201`

and out of this two, I only need `172.23.32.201` in one shot.

I tried two different methods to get it done:

```
1) I tried $(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') but does it guarantees that i get the host instance IP.

2) ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
This gives me all the ip address of every interface
```

Can anyone help me out in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple `ifconfig {interfacename}`?

To get only the IP-Address I would do:

```bash
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: what if you are running a program in linux machine where you dont know the actual interface name whether it is en0 or eth0 or something else ?
Actually i think the solution would rather be finding the actual interface of the host machine itself so as to account its not picking up any docker's IP or any VM's ip also , which will lead to getting the correct IP.

Comment: You do need to either know an interface name, or else only take the second line, assuming the number of IP's returned always stays the same. In the former case, edit the query suggested to include a cut, to remove the 'addr:':    "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'". In the latter, it's a bit brute force... but your query is fine, you just need to take the second line only... can use tail to do it: "ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | tail -n 1". But this isn't super accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: First you get the actual interface name of your machine then filter out the ip

`ifconfig $(route | grep '^default' | grep -o '[^ ]*$') | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: This is extra information, compared to your original post, where the interface that you are actually interested in is the default gateway (you could have more than one, with different metrics...). Please edit your original post to include this information. Your solution works if host names are resolved, but it can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the interface desired is the primary (lowest metric) gateway, try:

```
ip address show "$(ip route | grep '^default' | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $5 }')" | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk -F" " '{ print $2 }' | cut -d/ -f1
```

This uses the newer interface command, "ip" from the "iproute2" package, instead of the older "ifconfig" and "route" from "net-tools" package. The command can be shortened to use just "ip a show..." and "ip r...", but I used the full switch for clarity. With ifconfig/route:

```
ifconfig "$(route -n | grep '^0.0.0.0' | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $8 }')" | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Using "route -n" to prevent resolving host names.